# Unsure on how to output the results of this post from my servlet to anywhere

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

This will not shock any one here after reading this, however I am pretty new at "creating" java servlets.  I have pieced together the servlet below, largely from code I have found posted on various forums and boards.  I think this will do what I need, but I am missing a piece of the pie here somewhere.  I would like to replace out.println("I like Beer"); with out.println(Somevariablecontainingresults);  The intent is ultimately to post a query to an elasticsearch url using a xmlfile as the request body. The Url is within the network, but NOT on my webserver.  The xmlfile IS on my webserver.

Webserver: Tomcat 9

relevant section of web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HTTPRequestPoster</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Please</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HTTPRequestPoster</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypkg.HTTPRequestPoster</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

HTTPRequestPoster.java:

```
package mypkg;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HTTPRequestPoster extends HttpServlet {
/**
* Sends an HTTP GET request to a url
*
* @param endpoint - The URL of the server. (Example: " http://www.aviransplace.com")
* @param requestParameters - all the request parameters (Example: "param1=val1&param2=val2"). Note: This method will add the question mark (?) to the request - DO NOT add it yourself
* @return - The response from the end point
*/
public static String sendGetRequest()
{
String result = null;

String xmlFile = "/WEB-INF/adaptFeedbackQry.xml";
String endpoint = "https://femida-reporting-elasticsearch-iad.amazon.com/";
String elastiQry;

try {
    elastiQry = new Scanner(new File("xmlFile")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfEx) {
    elastiQry = "";
} 

if (endpoint.startsWith("http"))
{
// Send a GET request to the servlet
try
{
// Send data
String urlStr = endpoint + elastiQry;

URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();
// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
{
sb.append(line);
}
rd.close();
result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
return result;
} // EO public static String sendGetRequest()
//
//
/**
* Reads data from the data reader and posts it to a server via POST request.
* data - The data you want to send
* endpoint - The server's address
* output - writes the server's response to output
* @throws Exception
*/
public static void postData(Reader data, URL endpoint, Writer output) throws Exception{
    HttpURLConnection urlc = null;
    try {
        urlc = (HttpURLConnection) endpoint.openConnection();
        try 
        {
            urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        }   catch (ProtocolException e) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Shouldn't happen: HttpURLConnection doesn't support POST??", e);
        }
        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
        urlc.setDoInput(true);
        urlc.setUseCaches(false);
        urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=" + "UTF-8");
        OutputStream out = urlc.getOutputStream();
        try {
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
            pipe(data, writer);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("IOException while posting data", e);
        } finally
        {
            if (out != null) out.close();
        }
        InputStream in = urlc.getInputStream();
        try
        {
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            pipe(reader, output);
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("IOException while reading response", e);
        }   finally
        {
            if (in != null)
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {throw new Exception("Connection error (is server running at " + endpoint + " ?): " + e);} 
    finally
    {
        if (urlc != null) urlc.disconnect();
    }
}
/**
* Pipes everything from the reader to the writer via a buffer
*/
    private static void pipe(Reader reader, Writer writer) throws IOException {
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = reader.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            writer.write(buf, 0, read);
        }
    writer.flush();
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div>");
        out.println("<H1>I like Beer</h1>");
        out.println("</div></body></html>");
    } 

}
```

Comment: Just pass `response.getWriter()` as that `output` argument? Or is this too obvious?

Comment: from where is `sendGetRequest()` called? From where is `postData()` called?
In `sendGetRequest()`, do you append the file content (seems to be XML) as a query string to the URL? That won't work...

Comment: I don't know that I can answer either of your first two questions, other than pointing out where in the code they exist.  I am indeed appending the url with the query body from an xml file.  I found the bulk of this code on an older post from another site, and followed other posters direction.  It sound like I may have misunderstood something there, and am further from a solution than I had hoped.  If there are any resources you could direct me to it would be appreciated.  It sounds like I may need more than a simple answer to "What am I missing here".

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do? For example, are you trying to generate an XML document to post to a service, and then return the results of that request to the client who fired-off the request that generated the request-to-external-service?

Comment: I am trying to create a servlet that will "activate" when a user navigates to the URL mapped to the servlet. I would like that servlet to open the URL for a elaticseach server, and post to it the contents of my xml file (actually a JSON formatted request body).  Once that is working, I will also need to parse the results data, but I have not even written that part yet.  Currently I am stuck at even getting a result.  I started this by trying to reverse engineer source code from ruby, which I know even less about than I do Java.  Ultimately it will check if the user's id is in the result body.